# React Native - How to prevent unwanted unmounting of components?

Tags: react-native

I have a sort of WhatsApp clone project. From the users listing component, it will redirect to each users chatWindow. I dont want to re-render the chatWindow component which was already rendered.

This is what happening

1. Navigate to ChatWindow1 from Userchannel - ChatWindow1 mounted
2. Navigate to Userchannel from ChatWindow1 - ChatWindow1 unmounted
3. Navigate to ChatWindow2 from Userchannel - ChatWindow2 mounted
4. Navigate to Userchannel from ChatWindow2 - ChatWindow2 unmounted
5. Navigate to ChatWindow1 from Userchannel - ChatWindow1 mounted again.

I know using state we can render the ChatWindow again. But Is there a possibility to avoid the unwanted re-renderng. Currently I am usinf [RNRF](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) as the router.

Comment: Have you tried using shouldComponentupdate(nextProps, NextState) to control the re-renders? It should return a boolean value of true for re-render or false for don't re-render.

Comment: @SteveB The problem is its automatically unmounting the component, For many cases its really good.

Comment: If your user/app is switching screens as you describe, it would seem appropriate for the ChatWindow to re-render. If the ChatWindow and UserChannel were both subcomponents of a single component, you could use a hide/show technique but that would remove the RNRF router from the solution.  Is the rendering taking an extremely long time? Perhaps optimization in the rendering process is the ideal solution.

Comment: anybody found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Optimising re-render can be done in multiple ways in react.

1. You can use [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) Implementation where react itself shallow compares the props and re-renders only when necessary.
2. If you want more granular control, go with [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) which gives you a lifecycle method where you can compare the props and decide whether you want to avoid render. Please make sure the comparison is not complex. The more complex comparisons can make the app slow, in which case the **optimisation back fires**.
3. Use Flat list instead of List view or scrollview for better performance and make sure you add a keyExtractor and Item as a PureComponent.
4. Make sure the code splitting is properly done. you cannot optimise a very large amount code in a single page. If the components are small enough, you can optimise them better.
5. If you have a lot going on the JS, I would strongly recommend using a native navigation solution like [react-native navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation)

You can use console logs in render to find out the render count and take necessary actions. Please make sure that these optimisations can block necessary renders as well. So make sure props are different when you want to re-render things.

**Regarding the mount / unmount** 
In most cases the navigation keeps the screens in the stack. Going back will not trigger a re-render. You can do one thing, make sure page works on props, so that re-render happens only when data changes.

Helpful Links:

https://medium.com/@ohansemmanuel/how-to-eliminate-react-performance-issues-a16a250c0f27

https://medium.com/vena-engineering/optimizing-react-rendering-61a10e741edb

Answer (score 0):

Since your screens are unmounted there is nothing wrong to re-render when you navigate back to that screen. Of course you could avoid this by having all your screens mounted but that might cause memory leak.